# When was the pronunciation of 帧 changed?

Tags: pronunciation

I have the impression that in dictionary of 80's 帧 was still labeled as "zhèng" while in the 2000's it's been changed to "zhēn". There are also similar changes such as "qián" -> "xún" for 荨 in 荨麻疹, etc.

**Question**: When did the change for 帧 and 荨 happen specifically, and where to look up for an official document for such changes in general.

Comment: Probably, to zhēn, not zhē?

Comment: Yes, edited. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a short [Sina blog post](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4c0596f60102yg1x.html) that contains some explanations.

There was a《普通话异读词审音表》that was released in 1985. One of the words on the list was 帧:

> 帧。“装帧”指书画等物的装潢设计。《集韵·映韵》：“帧，张画绘也。”猪孟切，字书据此注为zhèn。声旁是贞，通行的读音是zhēn。《初稿》未审，《定稿》读为zhēn，与贞、侦读音一致。

On the same document you can also find 荨:

> 荨。《初稿》审订“荨麻”一词，定“荨”读qián，不取xún音。“荨麻”是一种植物，人如果被它刺伤，皮肤就刺痒起疹，成为“荨麻疹”。医生和病人把“荨麻疹”读为xúnmázhěn，与“荨麻”的读音不一致。《定稿》把“荨”字的读音分为文读和白读：文读读qián，如荨麻；白读读xún，如荨麻疹。

---

[Wikisource](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%AF%9D%E5%BC%82%E8%AF%BB%E8%AF%8D%E5%AE%A1%E9%9F%B3%E8%A1%A8%EF%BC%88%E4%BF%AE%E8%AE%A2%E7%A8%BF%EF%BC%89) has 普通话异读词审音表（修订稿）[2016] posted in full plain-text. Along with the [original 1985 version](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E8%AF%9D%E5%BC%82%E8%AF%BB%E8%AF%8D%E5%AE%A1%E9%9F%B3%E8%A1%A8).

Comment: Thanks. "猪孟切，字书据此注为zhèn": shouldn't 猪孟切 be "zhèng"?

Comment: 猪孟切 is surely zhèng.

Comment: But the passage also says 声旁是贞.。贞的读音是zhēn。